# Mappings between adaptive networks and Markov processes

Tags: graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, markov-chains

Are there any known mappings between adaptive networks models (i.e. graph model representations of networks where the internal vertex dynamics and connectivity topology can change subject to specific sets of constraints) and Markov chain/model representations of the state evolution of the structure of a network? In other words, given what is currently known about how to construct adaptive networks and model their evolving dynamics, are there any known 'isomorphic' or equivalent mappings or representations of such networks as Markov processes?

Note that I am attempting to keep the question as focused as possible here. But there are very specific reasons I am asking this relevant to some of our current theoretical work that I would be happy to elaborate on should additional details or clarifications be needed- if there is any interest in the question in the first place.